# Deleted Site Collection is still visible in View All Site Collection in Centeral Administration

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, site-collection, central-administration, site-deletion

I have deleted one of my site collection and when I check under `View All Site Collection` in Central Administration the deleted site collection is still appearing.

How can I remove that site from there also?

Comment: Are u sure, you deleted the correct site collection? What method you used to delete the site? Deleted site should not be visible via central admin...are u able to browse that site collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a site collection is deleted from **GUI**, the deleted site collection is stored in the `SPDeletedSite` object to be able to restore it back within `30 days` using [Restore-SPDeletedSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286319.aspx) cmdlet.

---

So to remove the site collection permanently from **SPDeletedSite** object, you should use `Remove-SPDeletedSite` cmdlet as the following

```
Remove-SPDeletedSite -Identity a valid server-relative URL or a valid GUID
```

> Note: to get valid GUID use [Get-SPDeletedSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286316.aspx)

For more details check [Remove-SPDeletedSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286317(v=office.14).aspx)

---

In case your issue still persists or you can't find your Site GUID in [Get-SPDeletedSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286316.aspx) list that means the site was not deleted properly so it is still shown in  **View All Site Collection** and in this case, you need to use [ForceDeleteSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323680.aspx) as the following:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://siteurl
$siteId = $site.Id
$gradualDelete = $false
$restorable = $true
$siteDatabase = $site.ContentDatabase 
$siteDatabase.ForceDeleteSite($siteId, $gradualDelete , $restorable)
```

---

By the way, To remove the site collection immediately, you should use PowerShell instead of GUI via `Remove-SPSite` –`GradualDelete:$False` cmdlet.

```
Remove-SPSite –Identity "http://sitename" –GradualDelete:$False
```

This operation is recommended for deleting very large sites but it's not recommended in case you intend to restore it back because it doesn't retain the SPSite object in the Gradual Site Deletion Queue.

> Note: it's recommended to backup a site collection before you delete
>   it using `GradualDelete:$False` because you will not be able to restore it

Read more about [Gradual Site Delete in SharePoint 2010](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2010/08/02/gradual-site-delete-in-sharepoint-2010/)