# SharePoint Online - Deleted site collection returned by Search REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection

I am listing all site collections of the company by calling:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site'&trimduplicates=false
```

Among the returned site collections, some are deleted. When navigating to them in the browser, there shows 404 File not found. And they cannot be seen in both active and deleted site in the new SharePoint admin center.

Is there any way to exclude deleted site collections in the API call? Or is there any way to search for a list of deleted site collections?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this answer https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220620/deleted-site-collection-is-still-visible-in-view-all-site-collection-in-centeral

Comment: Mine is SharePoint Online and the deleted site collections are not found in the Get-SPODeletedSite result. I believe they are permanently deleted since they are not seen in "Deleted Sites" in SharePoint admin center.